# Recursive in Postgresql 12.2

Tags: postgresql

I am using Ora2Pg tool to migrate from Oracle to Postgresql. My oracle code is

```
for rec_site in (select regexp_substr(p_site, '[^,]+', 1, level) site
                     from dual
            connnect by regexp_substr(p_site, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null) 
loop
```

The tool has converted this connect with prior as below postgresql script.

```
for rec_site in (WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
             select (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(p_site, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (level - 1)) site

             (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(p_site, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (level - 1)) is not null  

UNION ALL

             select (SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(p_site, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (level - 1)) site

             SELECT array_to_string(a, '') FROM regexp_matches(p_site, '[^,]+', 'g') AS foo(a) LIMIT 1 OFFSET (level - 1)) is not null JOIN cte c ON ()
) SELECT * FROM cte;
) loop
```

This code gives me syntax error. missing "LOOP" at end of SQL expression.

Comment: What exactly is the syntax error that you are getting?

Comment: Is this a pl/pgsql script? Could you try to use consistent indentation and casing? That would help to spot syntax mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a really poor translation for a hack in Oracle (and shows once more that automatic translation of procedural code very often leads to more work then manual translation)

The original Oracle query is a hack to split a delimited list into rows. This can be done a lot easier in Postgres:

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array(p_site, ',')) as t(site)
```

So you can use this:

```
for rec_site in select *
                from unnest(string_to_array(p_site, ',')) as t(site)
                where site is not null
loop
   ....
end loop;
```

This can be further simplified by iterating over the array directly:

```
foreach site in array string_to_array(p_site, ',')
loop
  ...
end loop;
```